# makedirs cannot create directory because it contains a question mark

Tags: python

Someone created an awesome script to download videos for personal use which is permitted under their TOS. However when the script tries to create a directory based on the title name, it creates an error due to a question mark "?" in the title. Windows does not permit special characters in the directory name. Is there a way to tell makedirs to ignore special character?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\nick.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\nick.py", line 88, in main
    episode.download()
  File "D:\nick.py", line 37, in download
    os.makedirs(dirname)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "The Crystal Maze\\What's The Sign For Winning?"
```

Comment: Hi.  Can you please show your code?  I need to know what version of python you are using, and what libraries.  Thanks

Comment: You can edit it yourself - `os.makedirs(dirname.replace('?', '_'))`

Comment: @Peter
Thanks for quick replies. I'm not a developer. So I couldn't figure which line to add this. 
On line 223 I see this:
` mkdir(name, mode) `
Do I replace that line with your suggestion?

Comment: That does work however since it is working on filename and subtitle filename too see new error:

Comment: ```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\download2.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\download2.py", line 88, in main
    episode.download()
  File "D:\download2.py", line 48, in download
    self._download_item(url, os.path.join(dirname, title))
  File "D:\download2.py", line 24, in _download_item
    with open(output + ".ttml", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "The Crystal Maze\\What's The Sign For Winning?\\What's The Sign For Winning?   S1.ttml"
```

Comment: To see the code: https://gist.github.com/relrelb/920370c07221b4b89b8999818e7fe899

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the symbols using this line:

```
''.join([i for i in name if i.isalnum() or i.isspace()])
```

You'll have to change `dirname` in the source code for what I wrote above:

```
os.makedirs(dirname) # in line 37, in download
```

It will save as the name, but without the symbols:

```
Out[58]: 'The Crystal Maze Whats The Sign For Winning'
```

Comment: I think that would be line 37 in a file called `download`? search for `os.makedirs(dirname)`

Comment: Yes line 37:
`
 def download(self):
  name = self.name.replace("/", " ")
  if '"' in name:
   name = name[name.index('"') + 1:name.rindex('"')]
  dirname = os.path.join(self.show.name, name)
  if not os.path.isdir(dirname):
   os.makedirs(dirname)
`

So it should look like this?

`
 def download(self):
  name = self.name.replace("/", " ")
  if '"' in name:
   name = name[name.index('"') + 1:name.rindex('"')]
  dirname = os.path.join(self.show.name, name)
  if not os.path.isdir(dirname):
   os.makedirs(''.join([i for i in name if i.isalnum() or i.isspace()]))
`

Comment: Apparently there's more to this... Since it relates to filename and subtitle filename too... Newest error:

Comment: ```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\download2.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\download2.py", line 88, in main
    episode.download()
  File "D:\download2.py", line 48, in download
    self._download_item(url, os.path.join(dirname, title))
  File "D:\download2.py", line 24, in _download_item
    with open(output + ".ttml", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "The Crystal Maze\\What's The Sign For Winning?\\What's The Sign For Winning?   S1.ttml"
```

Comment: To see the code: https://gist.github.com/relrelb/920370c07221b4b89b8999818e7fe899

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to do the same for the subtitle files. I think you hvlave to replace "title" this time. But I can't help you further I'm now afk

Comment: Thank you. got it. I added replace ?  to _ in two locations (line 32 and 46). It worked. You mentioned "title" which helped me. Thank you.